# smooth transition for projectile in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, projectile

just a quick question about projectiles in SpriteKit using swift. 
I have the following code for my "monster" that I want to shoot out shuriken smoothly however, it is right now just popping up at the randomized point, instead of smoothly shooting it out like from my character when I code it in the touhcesBegan function

Here's the code:

```
func monsterShoots() {

    let monsterShuriken = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "projectile-1")
    monsterShuriken.position = monster.position
    addChild(monsterShuriken)
    monster.position.y += CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(30)) - CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(30))

    monsterShuriken.position.x -= CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(1000))

    let actionMoveMonster = SKAction.moveTo(monsterShuriken.position, duration: 1.0)
    let actionMoveDoneMonster = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    monsterShuriken.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMoveMonster, actionMoveDoneMonster]))
}
```

and I repeat the action in didMoveToView with:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(monsterShoots),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
            ])
        ))
```

Thanks

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing more of your code. But it looks like you're first setting the monster and its shuriken positions first, so they jerk to those positions, and then you set up action, but by the time the actions run, they're pointless because you previously set the positions. Could be wrong. Just a guess. Haven't done sprite coding for awhile. But you should show more code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write this:

```
monster.position.y += CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(30)) - CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(30))
```

before this:

```
monsterShuriken.position = monster.position
```